# Split string into array in Android using a regex

Tags: android, arrays, regex, split

I need to split String that contains `[club123|ClubName]` and `[id123|UserName]` along with some other text into array without missing any characters and by putting this items separately.

For example, if I have a string like:

```
Hi, [id123|Alex]! Check out [club3123|this club]! It's fantastic!
```

I want to get an array like this:

```
[
    "Hi, ", 
    "[id123|Alex]", 
    "! Check out ", 
    "[club3123|this club]",  
    "! It's fantastic!"
]
```

The regexp for these words in brackets is:

```
\\[((id)|(club))[0-9]+\\|\\w+\\]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=[.?!])\s|\s(?=\\[)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=      # Beginning of the positive lookbehind
  [.?!]   # Match any character from the list: '.', '?', '!'
)         # End of the positive lookbehind
\s        # Match any whitespace character
|         # OR
\s        # Match any whitespace character
(?=       # Beginning of the positive lookahead
  \[      # Match a literal '['
)         # End of the positive lookahead
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Visualization]

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/XBV4C6)

---

It seems that the above expression is not working exactly as you wanted. After further clarification in the comments, I updated the regex:

```
((?:^|[.?!])[^\]\[]+)|(\\[[^\]\[]+\\])
```

**Explanation:**

```
(            # Beginning of 1st capturing group
  (?:        # Start non-capturing group
    ^|[.?!]  # Match line beginning or any characters from the list 
  )          # End of non-capturing group
  [^][]+     # Match any characters other than '[' and ']', one or more times
)            # End of 1st capturing group
|            # OR
(            # Beginning of 2nd capturing group
  \[         # Match a literal '['
    [^][]+   # Match any characters other than '[' and ']', one or more times
  \]         # Match a literal ']'
)            # End of 2nd capturing group
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Visualization]

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/8Rgkjl)

Comment: Nice to see the rarely seen `\h` in action. :)

Comment: Demo shows very strange result. zx81's pattern is closer to my question, but still a bit wrong

Comment: @inthy: The demo just shows the positions where the string is going to be split. You need to use this regex with Java's `String.split()` to create the required array.

Comment: @inthy: I don't know Java, but I put together a quick demo just for demonstration. Have a look: http://ideone.com/XBV4C6

Comment: Sorry, Amal, still wrong a bit.. It should be [id123|Alex], but not [id123|Alex]!

Comment: If I use string like "Hi, [id123|Alex]! [] Check out [club3123|this club]! It's fantastic!", it doesn't show [], though it should, according to my task... Idea is, that [id123123123| Username] or [club123123| Clubname] are special, others should be interpreted as just symbols

Comment: @inthy: You can try changing the expression to `((?:^|[.?!])[^\\]\\[]*)|(\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\])` to have `[]` returned, too. See [demo](http://ideone.com/8Rgkjl). These requirements were not mentioned in your original question, and it'd be a lot of work to update my answer every time to answer your new questions. Please ask this as a new question (and reference this Q&A if required). See also: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/220538)

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting vs. Matching**

Another option: to get your list, instead of splitting, match:

```
\[[^][]*\]|[^][]+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK1jA0).

**Token-by-Token Explanation**

```
\[                       # '['
[^][]*                   # any character except: ']', '[' (0 or more
                         # times (matching the most amount possible))
\]                       # ']'
|                        # OR
[^][]+                   # any character except: ']', '[' (1 or more
                         # times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: I need to find out  how to build such array: `["Hi, ", "[id123|Alex]", "! Check out ", "[club3123|this club]",  "! It's fantastic!"]` not just how to get these words in brackets

Comment: @inthy Exactly. Did you see the demo? These are exactly all the matches (they alternate colors). Not just those in brackets, but exactly the one you just said. :)

Comment: @inthy To make it easier for you to see, look at this [other demo](http://regex101.com/r/oG9bW8), where I added parentheses around the whole regex so that the matches are captured to Group 1: now in the bottom right panel you can see exactly all the matches. You don't need the parentheses in the regex, this is just for you to confirm. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit wrong. If I take `"Hi, [id123|Alex]! Check  ] out [club3123|this club]! It's fantastic!"` the `]` between `Check` and `out` won't be included into array, though it should (as written in my task

Comment: @inthy Really? You want something that works with unbalanced braces?